# RecyclerView and Firebase Storage fast scrolling ExoPlayer exception

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, scroll, exoplayer

So I have an android app which reads some Firebase Storage download URLs stored in Firebase Realtime Database. I also use a RecyclerView in order to render some ExoPlayers which play those videos.
The problem is that if I scroll really fast there is not enough time to render everything and the program throws an exception. 
 I think I have too many ExoPlayers being kept when I need to remove them as I go forward. How do I do that?

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error: index=0, type=video, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [640, 480, 29.997072], [-1, -1]), rendererSupport=YES
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [640, 480, 29.997072], [-1, -1])
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.createRendererException(BaseRenderer.java:359)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:563)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1254)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:756)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readToFlagsOnlyBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:814)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:712)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:599)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:329)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

This is the RecyclerView code:

```
   FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MediaObject> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MediaObject>()
                        .setQuery(databaseReference.orderByChild("title"), MediaObject.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MediaObject, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MediaObject, ViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i, @NonNull MediaObject mediaObject) {
                        viewHolder.setVideo(getApplication(), mediaObject.getTitle().replace(".mp4", ""), mediaObject.getMedia_url());
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.activity_view_extended_videolist, parent, false);

                        return new ViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        recycleView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

ViewHolder code:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View mView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    private PlayerView mExoPlayerView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setVideo(final Application ctx, String title, String url) {
        TextView mTextView = mView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        mExoPlayerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.exoplayer_view);

        mTextView.setText(title);
        try {
            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(ctx).build();
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
            exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ctx);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("2020-04-12");
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(video, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            mExoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
            exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ViewHolder", "exoplayer error " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using exoPlayer.release()

Comment: Did it work? I am facing same issue while scrolling up screen

Comment: Yea, it's working. It may not be the best solution though. I read that a good solution would be having a pool of about 5 ExoPlayers.  I don't really know how much more efficient it is that way. If an ExoPlayer gets outside the scroll window it will have to reload every time the user gets back to it.
But I was pressed by time and did this and it's working, efficient or not. For my situation it was better enough.

Comment: Yes exactly when I scrolling up to 10 to 13 videos it goes black with the error you mentioned

Comment: @Alex please post the new code with the release().  What does release do? now I need to recreate the player for every view in onBindViewHolder?